# PHP sort array 2 value

Tags: php, sorting

I need to sort "time" and "checkdanum".
For first sorting (time), it work.
**But the second sorting (checkdanum), it dose't work.**
it return     i need
50-3           **77-3**
77-3           **50-3**
46-3           46-3
84-2           84-2
74-2           74-2
74-2           74-2
48-2           48-2
75-1           75-1
70-1           70-1
46-1           46-1

Please help.

```
<?php

$dbx['x1']['inplay']['time'] = 84;
$dbx['x2']['inplay']['time'] = 77;
$dbx['x3']['inplay']['time'] = 75;
$dbx['x4']['inplay']['time'] = 74;
$dbx['x5']['inplay']['time'] = 74;
$dbx['x6']['inplay']['time'] = 70;
$dbx['x7']['inplay']['time'] = 50;
$dbx['x8']['inplay']['time'] = 48;
$dbx['x9']['inplay']['time'] = 46;
$dbx['x10']['inplay']['time'] = 46;

$dbx['x1']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 2;
$dbx['x2']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 3;
$dbx['x3']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 1;
$dbx['x4']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 2;
$dbx['x5']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 2;
$dbx['x6']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 1;
$dbx['x7']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 3;
$dbx['x8']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 2;
$dbx['x9']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 3;
$dbx['x10']['inplay']['checkdanum'] = 1;



$dbx = desc_sort($dbx , 'time');

$dbx = desc_sort($dbx,'checkdanum');
echo '<pre>';
foreach($dbx as $k => $v){
echo $dbx[$k]['inplay']['time'].'-'.$dbx[$k]['inplay']['checkdanum'].'<br>';
}

function desc_sort ($array, $key) {
    $sorter = array();
    $ret = array();
    reset($array);
    foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
        foreach ($array[$ii] as $k => $v){
            if($k == 'inplay'){
            $sorter[$ii] = $v[$key];
            }
        }
    }

    if (!function_exists('myComparison')) {
        function myComparison($a, $b){
            if(is_numeric($a) && !is_numeric($b))
            return -1;
            else if(!is_numeric($a) && is_numeric($b))
            return 1;
            else
            return ($a < $b) ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }

    uasort ( $sorter , 'myComparison' );
    foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
        $ret[$ii] = $array[$ii];
    }
    return $ret;
}
```

Comment: So descending by `checkdanum` and descending by `time`?

Comment: descending for both condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort both at the same time. If you're using PHP 7+ you can save some comparisons via the [spaceship operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). For example:

```
<?php   
uasort($dbx, function ($x,$y) {
   if (($x["inplay"]["checkdanum"] <=> $y["inplay"]["checkdanum"]) === 0) {
       return -($x["inplay"]["time"] <=> $y["inplay"]["time"]);
   } 
   return -($x["inplay"]["checkdanum"] <=> $y["inplay"]["checkdanum"]);
});
```

This [seems to work](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c1220de5c41458ae8d072879bf5816f9f1c7500d) and is much simplified.

For older PHP versions you can fallback to the function you defined as "myComparison".

Note: You can pad this with checks on whether the indices are there as well